# Submitting genealogy materials to US Library of Congress?

Tags: united-states, publishing, copyright

As of 2017-11-17, I'm still waiting for reply from the Local History and Genealogy Collection Development of the US Library of Congress, to my email on 2017-11-13:

> ```
> My late mother spent many hours researching
> our family history in various US libraries, 
> and made special trips to Europe to visit 
> sites and people.  Would her collection of 
> genealogical materials be of interest to the 
> Library?
>
> Our family is quite ordinary, with the possible 
> exception that she is buried in a National 
> Cemetery; my living father served in the military.
>
> I would not be offended if you answered no, but 
> would appreciate hearing back either way.
> ```

For reference, this is the LoC page on the topic:

http://loc.gov/rr/genealogy/gifts.html

Anyone care to share experiences submitting genealogy materials, published or unpublished, to LoC? In particular, I'm looking for any tips or considerations, such as

- pros and cons
- formats
- original materials or copies
- via Copyright Office or direct

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl from its history I cannot see any suggested edits on this question but I just approved one on Richard's other question by you.

Comment: @Richard - if you're posting here, I think that makes you an enthusiast anyway. And you likely have some expertise to share too. You're learning about dealing with the LoC, for one thing, and so could share that knowledge later if someone else asks. You're certainly welcome here!

Comment: Meta question : https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3302/6485

Comment: Apologies for not answering your original question sooner -- I've been meaning to, but it takes time to write a thoughtful answer.